REST API Design for Deleting One Resource and Updating Another
I am building a fullstack application with Next.js where users can invite other users to their household.
Resources:

Households
Invitations
Users

Action:
Accept an invitation. This will entail two dependent actions. If either of these fail the overall action of accepting the invitation fails and nothing is updated. The technical implementation of a rollback isn't important for this question, I don't think.

Delete the invitation.
Add the user to the household.
Send a notification to the household members that a new member was added (not dependent, i.e. if this fails the invitation is still accepted).

What is the best way to do this?
I am thinking about invitation/[id] DELETE with an action parameter equal to accept. FYI, I am using a Prisma transaction so the operation succeeds or fails as a whole.
The invitation could also be declined which would use the same endpoint invitation/[id] DELETE with an action parameter equal to decline and this would simply delete the invitation.
I am unclear if this follows REST API guidelines since two separate resources are being manipulated at once, and that isn't reflected in the URI.
I am open to other suggestions if you have a completely different approach.

DELETE should delete the resource at the uri you specified. It could have side-effects, but if you specifically want to model several actions in 1 transaction, maybe it's better to create a dedicated POST-style call for this?

@Evert thanks. It's nice to know side effects are a normal practice. There could be a POST or a PATCH to the household resource with a side effect of deleting the invitation. I think it depends what you see as the main action vs the side effect. I view the main action as deleting the invitation since the user is responding to it.

For what it's worth, I've actually implemented a CalDAV server. From my perspective it makes a bit more sense to submit the RSVP response as the main action, which could clean up any (now) irrelevant invitations. DELETE as the main verb to say: "I'm attending" feels a bit odd for me ;)

@Evert haha, that is a good point. I appreciate you taking the time to respond and the information you gave even if some of it is opinion based. Using the terminology side effects in my searches has exposed me to a lot of more useful results than I was getting before.

Please read the description of the [tag:api] tag which says "Do Not Use". Please follow the standards of this site.

I would identify the following resources with methods:
POST /households/{householdId}/candidates - add the user to the candidates to the household
GET /households/{householdId}/members - get all current members of the household
DELETE /households/{householdId}/members/{userId} - remove the user from the household
GET /users/{userId}/invitations - get all invitations of the user
POST /users/{userId}/invitations/{invitationId}:accept - accept the invitation
POST /users/{userId}/invitations/{invitationId}:decline - decline the invitation
For the latter cases, I created two custom methods. You can read more about custom methods in the Google API Design Guide.

P.S. After adding a user to candidates of the household, the user receives the invitation with a notification and after that the user should to accept or to decline the invitation.
After accept the user automatically is removed from the candidates and the user adds to the members of the household. The accepted invitation is automatically deleted.
After decline the user automatically is removed from the candidates. The declined invitation is automatically deleted.

Thanks for your contribution. Users are not invited to meetings but rather invited to join the household. Maybe when a user accepts an invitation I'll use POST households/133/members and pass the userId in the payload to add that user to the household and at the same time delete the invitation.

@Bro3Simon I tried to correct the answer after your comment.

Why would you add a user to a household before the invitation is accepted? Also, after the invitation is accepted or declined, why not delete the invitation?
What do you think about:
POST households/12/invitations with receiving userId in payload to create an invitation. DELETE households/12/invitations/34 ro reject an invitation.
POST households/12/members and pass the userId in the payload to add the user accepting the invitation to the household and at the same time delete the invitation.

@Bro3Simon that's a good point. I tried to develop your idea with the members in my answer, adding the candidates.


What is the best way to do this?

How would you do it with web pages?
There would probably be an "invitation" resource with a link that is sent to the invited user.  The representation of that resource would likely include a link to a form, which the user could submit to indicate acceptance of the invitation.  The submission of the form would cause the browser to create an HTTP POST request to the web server with the information provided by the user in the form; the target URI of the request would be computed by the browser using the form.action.
From the perspective of the browser, and other general purpose HTTP components, that is going to be a request that targets a single resource only; the server is, of course, allowed to modify its own resources as it sees fit.
Because the semantics of HTTP requests are constrained (in the common case) to a single target resource, you don't have a lot of flexibility to indicate changes to others.  You could look at the HTTP caching specification to see what kinds of things are possible; but note that those mechanisms have specific purposes within the HTTP application itself.
You could just send the results to a "handle invitation responses" resource; but if you were intended to leverage the document editing semantics built into the web you would normally either target the invitation resource or the household resource (since those resources are likely to change if the processing of the invitation is successful).
POST /invitations/12345
POST /households/67890

Would be the obvious candidates.

PUT /invitations/12345

You could do this; the user accepts or declines the invitation by sending an edited copy of the invitation back to the server.
PUT /households/67890

You probably wouldn't do this; it's legal, of course, but doing it correctly requires that the client know a lot about the processing of accepted invitations; I expect that you will be a lot more successful if you treat those as implementation details that should be hidden behind the facade that is your API.


I am thinking about invitation/[id] DELETE with an action parameter equal to accept.

This is not a "normal" choice; I would block any PR proposing this approach unless that PR also included a decision record thoroughly documenting the alternative designs considered.

Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect. -- RFC 9110

